# How to store stripe payment into database table

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment gateway in my website, I want store stripe payment in my database table, then I click, pay now button and form action redirect other page and that page show only strip Token, stripe Token Type, stripe Email these data price not showing

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email from the token that is passed back after initiating a payment in StripeCheckout.js using

```
token.email
```

This will return the email that the user entered in the 'pop-up' Stripe payment form displayed when the user presses the buy button.

You can also get the plan object from the token via

```
token.plan
```

which can be used in turn to get the plan amount.

More info on the exact process can be found here
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial

Comment: thanks sir but it's not better solution for me because i want use popup stripe payment form that not pass payment on other page..

Comment: Believe it or not, this approach is using checkout.js which allows you to either process the data on the same page with JS or process it on a different page with PHP for example. In fact, you can do all the processing on one page if you wish.

Comment: sir i am using stripe payment gateway on first time i want fetch all payment data from other page if you have any example please give me that link i am confusing how i can get all post data please forward me link if you have